# Can only victor way be used for route in cross country?

Tags: ifr-navigation

In IFR low-en route chart, there are many ways related to victor ways. Do I have to select the route for cross county? Or, Can I choose the ways between victor ways?

Comment: Are you asking about a specific country? In some parts of the world (e.g. Asia) routes are very strictly controlled; in others (e.g. United States) there's a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You just use (starting waypoint)  DCT  (ending waypoint) in your flight plan (DCT = Direct) and submit that.  It's up to ATC to approve that routing and you'll find out when you are issued your clearance.

Especially at lower altitudes it's likely you'll be cleared as filed, but there's always a chance they'll shift your route a bit to improve traffic flow for whatever reason, adding waypoints or moving you to an adjacent V airway, doing their best to minimize any increase in your distance.

Answer (score 0):

You can request any way you want. The actual IFR clearance given may be something else altogether, depending on other traffic, and possibly even GPS direct from your current location to a waypoint near to the intended point of landing if conditions are favorable.

Comment: Your routing will also be impacted by where you are starting from. I depart from a non-towered airport, typcially with a void-time clearance (have to be airborne and contact ATC within a time-limit). The clearance is usually to fly some heading where the Class B overlying the airport can confirm it's me they see on radar, then a heading change or two before being released to a first waypoint farther along on my planned route.  If I can depart VFR instead and get away from the Class B before asking for IFR, there is a lot less fooling around to start the trip.